# MVC3 AJAX passing data to controller. It's being submitted twice

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

So I have a table that gets transformed to an array using:

```
var result = $("#enrolledStudents").sortable('toArray');
```

But when I go a head an pass that into my controller like so:

```
$("#update-enroll").click(function () {
            var result = $("#enrolledStudents").sortable('toArray');
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Enrollment", "Classroom")',
                data: { students: result },
                type: 'POST',
                traditional: true
            });
        });
```

My debugging breakpoint gets set off twice, causing issues to arise. What is the proper way to submit data to my controller on POST?

Comment: Look at your loaded scripts and make sure that the unobtrusive file(s) are not being loaded twice. I've seen this happen when the events are hooked twice. Also, is the button "update-enroll" a submit type button? If so, then you're hooking an event to click the button that is submitting the form and then you're doing another call. Can you provide the HTML of the form?

Comment: Yes, I had to do that? I have a variable var result .... that I need passed in as a parameter and if I didn't do it this way, it'd come out as NULL, how can I fix that? I would prefer not hooking an event to click the button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per my comments, there are a couple things that could be causing this.

1. You have have the unobtrusive file(s) loaded multiple times
2. Your form has an action method defined, and your button is inside the form tag as a submit button. This will submit the form, and then the click will also submit the form - see example

**Example**

```
<form action="/somerowout/someaction">
  <input type="text" id="text1"/>
  <input type="text" id="text1"/>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

If you need to validate a value on your form before posting, don't hook up an additional Ajax call. Your javascript will look something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").submit(function(){
        var result = $("#enrolledStudents").sortable('toArray');
        if(result == null){
            //do something to show validation failed
            return false;
        }
        return true;        
    });
});
```

And your form code would then look something like:

```
@using (@Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { })) { 
    <input type="text" id="text1"/>
    <input type="text" id="text1"/>
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

---

If you want to use Ajax rather than the Html Helpers, use a div instead of a form, and you won't get a duplicate post. Here's how you could achieve this:

```
<div id="enrolledStudents">
  <--! your elements -->
  <button id="saveStudents">Save</button>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("saveStudents").click(function(){
        var result = $("#enrolledStudents").sortable('toArray');
        if(result !== null){ /* do some kind of check here. */
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Enrollment", "Classroom")',
                data: { students: result },
                type: 'POST',
                traditional: true,
                success : function(data) {
                    if (data.status) {
                        window.location = data.route;
                    }               
                }
            })
        } else {
            /* notify ui that save didn't happpen */
        }           
    });
});
```

**Example Controller Action**
When posting your data using Ajax, here's an example of how to pass the route

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomethingPost(SomeModel model) {
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest()) {
        var json = new {
                   status = true,
                   route = @Url.RouteUrl("MyRouteName", new { /* route values */ })
        };
        return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Comment: where is code to pass var result to my controller's parameter?

Comment: Since your example didn't include HTML code, I assumed that "#enrolledStudents" is inside your form tag. is it not?

Comment: Sorry. #enrolledStudents is the ID of a tbody inside a table. I'm using the jquery sortable to serialize the table rows (this is working). I've changed my code to be similar to yours but now my RedirectToAction inside my controller does not work. How come?

Comment: Since your call is most likely an ajax call, then you can't use the RedirectToAction. I'll update the example with a suggestion of how to deal with this.

Comment: I've updated my example. see "success" function and example controller.

Comment: I had the same behavior and sure enough I had the unabtrusive script loaded twice. Many thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are preventing the default behaviour (form POSTING) of the submit button ? use `preventDefault` to do so.

```
$("#update-enroll").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
 //rest of the code

});
```

**EDIT : As per the comment**

To do the redirect in the ajax handler, you need to return the URL to be redirected in a `JSON` Response back to the calle.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Classroom(string students)
{
  //do some operaton
  if(Request.IsAjax())
  {
     //This is an Ajax call
     return Json(new
                   {
                     Status="Success",
                     NewUrl = Url.Action("Index","Home")
                   });
  }
  else
  {
     //Normal request. Use RedirectToActiom
      return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
  }

}
```

Now in your ajax call check the JSON result and do the redirect.

```
 $.ajax({
         url: '@Url.Action("Enrollment", "Classroom")',
         data: { students: result },
         type: 'POST',           
         dataType: "json",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         success: function (data) {
               if(data.Status=="Success")
               {
                  window.location.href = data.Newrl;
               }
               else
               {
                   alert("some error");
               }
         }

});
```

Comment: Okay, so now with that, my code inside my controller return RedirectToAction("Index"); doesn't work. How can I fix this?

Comment: Since it is an ajax call, RedirectoToAction wont work, you may send a JSON response back to the calle and use that to redirect. Code coming..

Comment: As mentioned above I'm not too happy about creating a new event hook to send ajax over, thus causing the two submits. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Sorry, but the above answer seems like a hack to the issue. If you aren't using a form for it's intended use, then don't use it.Just  serialize the data to be sent back via Ajax. Please see my updated example.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you don't have the jquery files loaded twice. I had this behavior and the problem was files loaded twice.